# Istio Virtual Service with Knative Service External Name

Tags: kubernetes, istio, knative

I feel like this should be a simple thing, to point an istio virtual service to a knative service, that gets stood up as an `ExternalName` type.

```
  - match:
    - authority:
        prefix: demo.example.io
      gateways:
      - knative-serving/knative-ingress-gateway
      - cert-manager/secure-ingress-gateway
      uri:
        prefix: /api
    retries:
      attempts: 5
      perTryTimeout: 15s
      retryOn: gateway-error,connect-failure,refused-stream
    route:
    - destination:
        host: proxy.default.svc.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

This throws a 404. If I use a regular service it works fine. Or if I point to the first revision `proxy-0001.default.svc...` it works fine.

Comment: few clarifications required.  trust above virtualservice is created for egress gateway not for ingress gateway.  in the shared virtualserivce ingress gateway details are mentioned.  Also its better to use to proper name instead of "host: proxy" in route definition.  for better readability its good to use host: <service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal This is for an ingress gateway. Knative creates an External Name type service for incoming traffic. It is the service that all my internal logic points to:

`proxy.default.svc.local:80`

https://knative.dev/docs/serving/services/private-services/

Comment: you can check ingress gateway pod access logs and see whether its forwarding this to actual pod

Comment: check the routing.yaml in this example, https://github.com/knative/docs/tree/main/code-samples/serving/knative-routing-go